# How to select Sqlparameter list element by name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to select Sqlparameter list element by name?

```
        SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[]
        {
             new SqlParameter("@UserID",UserID),
             new SqlParameter("@startDate",startDate)
        };
```

When I want to got UserID,Then I need use `para[0].value` to get element value.

```
        Response.Write(para[0].value);
```

but its need to use `int` to get element.

Have any method to get element by 'Name', like `para["UserID"].value`?

Comment: No you can't because `para` is an array of `SqlParameter`. So one way is to  do it with LINQ as suggested by @User2012384

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a work around for you:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WeothY

Use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx) to select the parameter

```
var parameter = para.Where(a=>a.ParameterName == youParameterName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can be refactored like this var parameter = para.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ParameterName == youParameterName)

Comment: If I want to modify all element value at once to Excute SQL comand with `SqlParameter[]` , Does it mean I need to set varied parameter ? [simulate code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SfmMAS)

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand your question, what do you mean by need to set varied parameter??

Comment: Sorry , It's my fault . I'm just in confuse . Now Im get clear it before I thought it over ! My problem solved ! Thank you !